# ZF2 REST based authentication

Tags: rest, zend-framework2

I would like to create an AngularJS application, that will communicate with backend of ZF2.
How can I make user's authentication? Please show me an easy example.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app - sample app.

There is a good [security](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/tree/master/client/src/common/security) model in it.